# Tomcat performance issue with many simultaneous connections and scalling

Tags: java, tomcat, connection-pooling, ubuntu-14.04

I am running a Tomcat 7.0.55 instance with a Spring REST service behind on Ubuntu 14.04LTS server. I am doing performance tests with Gatling. I have created a simulation using a front-end application that accesses the REST backend.

My config is:

```
Total RAM: 512MB, 1 CPU, JVM options: -Xms128m -Xmx312m -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m
```

The environment might not seem to be very efficient, but if I do not cross the limit of the ~700 users (I process 90k requests in 7 minutes) I get all request processed successfully and very quickly.

I am starting having issues when there are too many connections at the same time. The failing scenario is that there are around 120k requests in 7 minutes. Problems start to begin when there are around 800 concurrent users in play. Until the number of users is 600-700, all goes fine, but after this limit I am starting getting exceptions:

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Request timed out to /xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080 of 60000 ms
        at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.timeout.TimeoutTimerTask.expire(TimeoutTimerTask.java:43) [async-http-client-1.8.12.jar:na]
        at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.timeout.RequestTimeoutTimerTask.run(RequestTimeoutTimerTask.java:43) [async-http-client-1.8.12.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelTimeout.expire(HashedWheelTimer.java:556) [netty-3.9.2.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelBucket.expireTimeouts(HashedWheelTimer.java:632) [netty-3.9.2.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$Worker.run(HashedWheelTimer.java:369) [netty-3.9.2.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108) [netty-3.9.2.Final.jar:na]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_55]
12:00:50.809 [WARN ] c.e.e.g.h.a.GatlingAsyncHandlerActor - Request 'request_47'
 failed : GatlingAsyncHandlerActor timed out
```

I thought this could be related to small jvm. However, when I upgrade the environment to:

```
Total RAM: 2GB, 2CPUs, JVM options: -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

I still get very similar results. The difference in failed requests is insignificant..

I've been playing with setting the Tomcat connector with no effect. The current tomcat settings are:

```
<Connector enableLookups="false" maxThreads="400" maxSpareThreads="200" minSpareThreads="60" maxConnections="8092" port="8080" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" connectionTimeout="20000" keepAliveTimeout="10000" redirectPort="8443" />
```

Manipulating the numbers of threads, connections, keepAliveTimeout didn't help at all to get the 800 concurrent users to work with no timeouts. I was planning to scale the app to handle at least 2k concurrent users, but so far I can see that vertical scaling and upgrading the env gives me no results. I also do not see any issues with memory through jvisualvm. The OS shoudln't be a limit, the ulimits are set to either unlimited or high values.. The DB is not a bottleneck as all REST is using internal caches.

It seems like tomcat is not able to process more than 800 connected users in my case. Do you have any ideas of how these issues could be adressed? I would like to be able to scale up to at least 2k users and keep the failed rate as low as possible. I will appreciate any thoughts and tips how I can work it out. If you need more details, please leave a comment.

Cheers
Adam

Answer (score 0):

Do you increase open file number.Every connection consume a open file item.

Comment: Yes, I did. I have set it to 4000, no improvement.

Comment: Are you sure the tomcat process is picking up the ulimit? You may want to try setting it in Tomcat's startup.sh.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably hitting the limit on TCP connections given that you are creating so many in such a short time. By default Linux waits a while before cleaning up connections. After the test fails, run `netstat -ant | grep WAIT | wc -l` and see if you are close to 60,000. If so, that indicates you can do some tuning of the TCP stack. Try changing the following `sysctl` settings:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl = 15
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes = 5
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 5
```

You can also try some other settings mentioned in [this ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/357799/improving-tcp-performance-over-a-gigabit-network-with-lots-of-connections-and-hi).

Comment: The netstat grep WAIT returned 40 results, not 60k. 

However, I made a change to the tomcat connector and changed it to Non blocking NIO. So far, this allowed me to increase performance by 50%. When I manage to improve it more I will make relevant notes in my question.

Comment: So the 50% improvement was done with the NIO connector type. This seems to have impact on the overall performance, however, still when the number of concurrent users reaches the number of 800 i keep getting timeout exceptions. Hence this remains unresolved.